# Comments on Arabic version of page are not shown under content after admin approval

Tags: 8, comments

I am working with drupal8 website. Here am using both arabic and english translation. Authenticated users have the permission to post and view the comments. When an auhenticated user posted a comment to an arabic content and after admin approval the comment is not showing for authenticated users side. Admin can see the comments only authenticated users have this problem. There is no issue with english comments. Could i miss anything here?

Comment: Question is not clear.  Its not showing for authenticated users ? do you mean admin can actually see the comment ?

Comment: Yes..admin can see the comments.Other authenticated users cant see their own comments after admin approval from the backend.